# Simultaneous equations with two unknowns

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

The question I've been given is
$$\begin{array}{c|c}t&v\\\hline3&38\\12&200\end{array}$$
Modelling equation is
$$v=k\sqrt{t-a}$$
Calculate $a$ and $k$.

I tried to solve like:

$$38 = k \sqrt{12-a}$$
$$200 = k \sqrt{3-a}$$

$$162 = k \sqrt{12-a} - k \sqrt{3-a}$$

$$\frac{162}k = \sqrt{12-a} - \sqrt{3-a}$$

$$(162/k)^2 = 12-a - 3 + a$$

$$(162/k)^2 = 9$$

$$162/k = 3$$

$$162/3 = k$$

$$k = 54$$

WHICH IS GIVEN AS WRONG. $k$ should be $65.45$

Comment: [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) resources to learn how to typeset maths.

Comment: You swapped $3$ and $12$ !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that in general this question would be easier if you were to square both sides:

$$
v^2=k^2(t-a)
$$

With the two $(t, v)$ pairs of $(3, 38)$ and $(12, 200)$, we have

$$
1444 = 3k^2-ak^2 \\
40000 = 12k^2-ak^2
$$

Subtracting the former from the latter gives us

$$
9k^2 = 38556 \\
k^2 = 4284
k = \sqrt{4284} \approx 65.452
$$

Then substituting $k^2 = 4284$ back into either of the above yields

$$
a = 12-\frac{40000}{4284} = 3-\frac{1444}{4284} \approx 2.663
$$

Assuming that this model is supposed to produce real numbers as output, the implication is that it cannot be used for $t < a$.

Comment: Thanks, that got it

Answer (score 0):

First mistake:

- When time is $3$, the volume is $38$.
- When time is $12$, the volume is $200$.
- You have made the mistake of thinking when time is $3$, the volume is $200$. Similary for the other equation.

Second mistake:

- In general, $(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b})^2 \ne a - b$.

Guide:

- You might like to divide the equations rather than subtract the equations.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that (a−−√−b√)2≠a−b. I forgot that

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, you have in fact $$38 = k \sqrt{3-a}\tag 1$$
$$200 = k \sqrt{12-a}\tag 2$$ Make the ratio
$$\frac{38}{200}=\frac{\sqrt{3-a} } {\sqrt{12-a} }$$ Square both sides to get
$$\frac{361}{10000}=\frac{3-a}{12-a}\implies a=\frac{2852}{1071}$$ Plug in $(1)$ to get $k=6 \sqrt{119}\approx 65.4523$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the model as

$$k^2t-k^2a=v^2$$

and you have a system of two *linear* equations in the unknowns $k^2$ and $k^2a$.

$$\begin{cases}3k^2-k^2a&=38^2,\\12k^2-k^2a&=200^2.\end{cases}$$

Then solving the system

$$k^2= 4284,$$  $$k^2a=11408.$$

The rest is easy.